# Corrupt restoration image on laptop

Tags: windows-xp, boot, restore

My Windows XP laptop went to start up and it gives me this message:

> The system could not be restarted from
>   its previous location  because the
>   restoration image is corrupt.
>
> Delete
>   restoration data and proceed to system
>   boot menu

Does anyone know what this means and what I should do?

Answer (score 2):

This is an indication that your hiberfil.sys file is corrupt.

To resolve the issue, you'll need to:

1. Disable hibernation:*Control Panel -> Display -> Screen Saver -> Power -> Monitor -> Uncheck "Enable Hibernation" -> Apply and OK*
2. Reboot
3. Re-enable hibernation
4. Reboot

Comment: I cannot get to the control panel, the computer will not start up.  How do I get past this message and force the computer to start up so I can do as you suggested.  I have Windows XP.

Comment: Did you try to start up in recovery mode? After restarting your pc, after the POST screen (usually is the "black" one followed by your motherboard manufacturer), keep hitting F8, enter recovery mode and do the steps said by Murdoch Ripper. If it works for you dont forget to mark this answer as accepted! :)

Comment: Try pressing F8 right before Windows starts to load and see if there is a "delete restoration data" option in the menu.